# Включение поддержки стандарта с++11 в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Я понимаю, как включить поддержку 11 стандарта С++ в каждом отдельном проекте Qt. В .pro файле пишем:

```
CONFIG += C++11
```

и все работает.

Можно ли настроить Qt Creator, чтобы он **автоматически** добавлял эту строчку в файл проекта? Т.е. каждый вновь создаваемый проект должен сразу создаваться с этой опцией. Гугл как-то не очень помогает...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В папке Qt Creator'а есть каталог

```
share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\projects
```

В нём - папки, имя которых соответствует типу создаваемого проекта. Внутри папки лежит файлик `file.pro`. Этот файл - шаблон для нового проекта.

Comment: Спасибо! добавлю (м.б. кому пригодится) свой путь в Убунту: `/opt/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/projects/`. Там папки типа `plainc`, `qmake` и т.п., в которых уже и лежат искомые файлики.